# Call of Duty: Modern Warfare - Reflex Edition difficulty setting stays the same

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I have Call of Duty: Modern Warfare - Reflex Edition for the Wii.

- I beat the game on recruit.
- I beat it again on regular.

But when I go to mission select, it says I beat it on recruit. Aftermath and The Coup De Al-Elasad say regular, but not the others.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Beat one of them again on Regular. If it says Regular, then you have to beat them all again, but if it says Recruit there is something wrong with the game or actually the Wii itself. But just try one mission that says Recruit, again.